# MySQL Query Logs Truncating Queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-logic

I'm looking at the general log I've enabled in MySQl and it's working nicely.
However, queries appear to be truncated a little over 1000 characters.

What's the deal with that?

Comment: What version are you using?  Could it be [this bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=21557) affecting you?

Comment: 5.1 so I guess it's possible.  Is this resolved in 5.5?  You should submit your comment as an answer as it appears to be THE answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should also change the field type, the 'argument' field is medium text, you should change it to 'longtext' with the following query.

```
ALTER TABLE `mysql`.`general_log` CHANGE `argument` `argument` LONGTEXT NOT NULL;
```

what kind of query is so great than 1000?

maybe logging a BLOB field?